# PHP PDO mySQL query - the most efficient method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lag

I have a database that contains 4 relationship tables used to construct the content of a page:

```
content    rel     theme     theme_meta
```

The `rel` table matches the `contentID` from the `content` table to the corresponding `rel` field of the `theme` table. `theme_meta` has a field called `themeID` that links it to the `theme` table.

So

When constructing a page at the moment I `JOIN` the content table to the del table, joining that to the `theme` table and that to the `theme_meta` table.

It gives me around 24 rows for each matched row of the `content` table.

I then use a some php `foreach` loops to restructure the results into multidimensional arrays per `content` row.

Is that efficient? Would it be faster and more efficient to make 2 calls to the database, one for `content` and one for `theme`. This would produce far fewer rows and be easier to work with but require a second call to the database.

Comment: Your current approach (a single query) is usually the best way.  Database queries incur a lot of overhead.

Comment: Fewer rows? Both methods should result in the same amount of rows overall!?!? Oh, and what eggyal said +1

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, an approach that uses a single query is usually the best way (since database queries incur a lot of overhead).

Indeed, it sounds as though your alternative approach would loop over the results of one query (on the `content` table) each time calling some other query (on the other tables) to fetch the joined data: such an approach will prove very costly in the long-term and will not scale well.

Therefore, to assemble a multi-dimensional array from the data, you merely need sort the joined results accordingly and keep track of the last seen identifier as you loop over the resultset (in order to detect when one needs to traverse up a level within the resulting array):

```
$qry = $dbh->query('
  SELECT   *
  FROM     content
      JOIN rel        USING (contentID)
      JOIN theme      USING (rel)
      JOIN theme_meta USING (themeID)
  ORDER BY contentID
');

$arr = array();

$row = $qry->fetch();
while ($row) {
  array_push($arr, array());
  $cid = $row['contentID'];
  do {
    array_push(end($arr), $row);
  } while ($row = $qry->fetch() and $row['contentID'] == $cid);
}

echo var_export($arr);
```

I would however caution that it is often unnecessarily costly to build such a PHP data structure from the results of a database query, as one can might be able to build and dispatch the requisite output whilst reading the resultset.

Comment: Thanks. Very informative and I have managed it with something very similar.